# value of type uipickerview has no member text

Tags: swift, xcode, uipickerview

i am trying to assign my pickerview data but what data type member is picker view?
when i use text it says the error "value of type uipickerview has no member text"

```
dateLabel.text = shiftItem.day
timing.text = shiftItem.slot
```

the ibaction is

```
    @IBOutlet weak var timing: UIPickerView!
```

so for label or text field the data type would be text but what is it for pickerview?
this may seem like a dumb question but i could not find the answer anywhere

also, how can i pass the data a user has selected on a pickerview to another view controller?

thank you so much for all the help!

Comment: See the doc on how populate a `PickerView`: `You provide the data to be displayed in your picker view using a picker data source—an object that adopts the UIPickerViewDataSource protocol. Use your picker view delegate—an object that adopts the UIPickerViewDelegate protocol—to provide views for displaying your data and responding to user selections.`. So use `UIPickerViewDataSource`, there are plenty of tutorial about that.

Answer (score 0):

`UIPickerView` doesn't have any property named `text`. You have to use an array of String as it's datasource. Here is an example.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
    
    let pickerData: [String] = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerData[row]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
// use the row to get the selected row from the picker view
// using the row extract the value from your datasource (array[row])
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Please use the below code for it. Picker View doesn't have a text member.

```
class HomeController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

var dataArray: [String] = ["Aman", "Raju", "Amit", "Aashish", "Sheshnath"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self
    // Use this method for initial text from your data array
    pickerView.selectRow(1, inComponent: 0, animated: true)

}
}

extension HomeController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int 
{
        return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return dataArray.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return dataArray[row]
}
}
```

[image]